# Change fragment from ViewModel in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am developing an agenda app for practise MVVM architecture and SQLite databases but i need to change fragment from inside of fragment. So for calendarFragment i created this viewModel but i can't use .supportFragmentManager method without MainActivity context. How can i solve this problem ?

```
class calendarFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun fragmentChanger(fragment : Fragment, context: Context?) {
        var transaction = (context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(com.cagataysencan.agendea.R.id.frameLayout,fragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not be doing that in ViewModel, should be doing in Fragment OR Activity.

Comment: use activity?.supportFragmentManager

Comment: To expand on @QAMAR comment. By convention a `ViewModel` should react to things like button clicks i.e. `onNewSearch(text : String)` - only when the `ViewModel` has a reason to change state/data.  Conversely the `View` just needs to observe state and data changes, be it live data, live data + data binding, stateflow, state flow + data binding, Composables etc ..  Your `fragmentChanger` does not represent a state or data change to the `ViewModel` thus doesn't belong there.  However the system, as a result of your method will call `ViewModel::onCleared` as a side effect, which is a state change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LiveData with your ViewModel for this purpose.

Observe the LiveData from your Fragment and once that LiveData provides an update, we'll get it in Fragment. Inside the callback, you can launch from the observing fragment.